# different results coming from biomart online and biomaRt R library

Tags: r, biomart, gene-ontology

I am playing with biomart in order to get the list of genes associated to a specific gene ontology (GO) term.

So, if I use the webservice as in this [query](http://www.ensembl.org/biomart/martview/b222cd479ae7a7ab534cc7d672a80df5):

I get at least 50 genes. If I download the file I can gen an exact count of them:

```
$ cat mart_export.txt | wc -l
347
```

Now, I can do the same operation by using the R library biomaRt. Specifically:

```
> ensembl <- useEnsembl(biomart="ENSEMBL_MART_ENSEMBL", dataset='hsapiens_gene_ensembl')
> gene <- getBM(attributes = c('external_gene_name'), filters = 'go', values = 'GO:0030098', mart = ensembl)
> unique(gene)
  external_gene_name
1               SPI1
2              PRKDC
3                TOX
4               LY6D
5               CBFB
6              IKZF1
7               RELB
8             FLT3LG
```

By doing so, these are all the genes I retrieve. The two results are totally different and I don't know why it. All these eight genes are found in the biomart file (I grepped it, to be sure).

I believe this is not [an issue related to databases versions](https://www.biostars.org/p/109246/) since I checked:

```
>listMarts()
               biomart               version
1 ENSEMBL_MART_ENSEMBL      Ensembl Genes 94
2   ENSEMBL_MART_MOUSE      Mouse strains 94
3     ENSEMBL_MART_SNP  Ensembl Variation 94
4 ENSEMBL_MART_FUNCGEN Ensembl Regulation 94
```

and:

```
>listDatasets(ensembl)
...
38 Human genes (GRCh38.p12)
...
```

Both are the same version used by biomart online.

What is going on? Is it possible that biomart online is considering [GO relations](http://geneontology.org/page/ontology-relations) that are not specified in the R version?

Comment: Funny: if I count the result of your query I get that there would be 361 genes. While we have 346 genes (you need to discount the header, and also as a tip `wc -l mart_export.txt` works as well). The difference between 361 and 346 might be duplicated gene, which suggests that they are considering GO child process. But I think that Emily might have a better answer for this. Have you searched online for similar questions?

Comment: yes, you're rigth about the header ;-) I forgot about it. also yes I looked for other similar questions and I found the one that suggested me to check the version used by R biomaRt. Another similar question https://www.biostars.org/p/14948/ does not answer. How come that you get 361 lines? I'll try that again, sending another equal query. Lets see

Comment: Ok, I tried again and I still got 346 genes! This is weird!

Comment: The 361 is using the count feature of the query page. Instead of results I pressed count at the top left header. If you deselect the unique rows you'll get more genes

Comment: yes, I tried it but actually I don't know. Hopefully unique genes will be enough!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry, this was my mistake in the last question. To search down the ontology, rather than just for the specific association with a term, biomaRt needs a different filter: 'go_parent_term'.

Try:

```
gene <- getBM(attributes = c('external_gene_name'), filters = 'go_parent_term', values = 'GO:0030098', mart = ensembl)
```

Comment: ooook, that works perfectly!
A small point, though. Is this using only "is_a" relations or is it using any kind of GO relations?

Comment: These are the mapping we use between parent and child: biological_process = is_a,part_of,regulates,positively_regulates,negatively_regulates;
cellular_component = is_a,part_of;
molecular_function = is_a,part_of